# Diagonalization of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&3\\3&-5&3\\6&-6&4\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

We need to find whether the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&3\\3&-5&3\\6&-6&4\end{pmatrix}$$
is diagonalizable. If so, we have to find the diagonal matrix and also the matrix that will diagonalize it.

I have found out the eigen values: $-2,-2,4.$
And using the eigen values, the supposed diagonal matrix is$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&0&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&4\end{pmatrix}.$$

But I need to prove that $D=P^{-1}AP.$ That's where the problem arises:

1. I have a problem in finding the eigen vectors. How can I find the eigen vector when the eigen value is $-2?$ I am getting only one equation!
2. Also, how can I find the "$P$" so that I can do $P^{-1}AP?$ (If I had 3 different eigen values and for that if we had got 3 different eigen vectors, finding $P$ was pretty straight forward. But here we have 2 repetitions of the same eigen value and I can't even find out the eigen vector.)

Comment: @PrincessEev  actually i get one equation when i put λ=-2 in : Ax=λx
And the equation is x1-x2+x3=0

Comment: Well done! So this eigen-subspace is of dimension $2.$ You can choose 2 linearly independent vectors in it.

Comment: @AnneBauval ok, but I will get different values of "P" when I put two different values right?

Comment: Right, the matrix $P$ is not unique.

Comment: @AnneBauval So the matrix i get is [1 -1 1; 1 0 1; 0 1 0].. as it det=0, I cant find P-1

Comment: Don't take 3 vectors in your plane. Only 2, and take an eigenvector for 4 as your third column for P

Comment: @AnneBauval  yeah i did that... for 4, the vector is 1,1,0

Comment: No it is not. Recalculate. That vector cannot be eigen for 4 since it is in the eigenplane for -2

Comment: @AnneBauval yeah sorry... and thanks!

Comment: Btw, note that you could not know that $A$ was diagonalizable just from knowing the eigenvalues $-2,-2,4.$ You had to calculate the eigenspace for $-2,$ to find it was of dimension 2 and not 1.

Comment: @AnneBauval yeah I know that, but I was asked to pove it with A-1AP. Btw, can you please say if this "P" has a specific name? Just asking.

Comment: Sorry english is not my native language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix Maybe "transition matrix".

Comment: @AnneBauval ok thanks

Comment: Note moreover that the eigensubspaces are *always* independent. So, having found a non-invertible $P,$ you *should* have guessed you just made some calculation mistake.

Comment: @AnneBauval yeah i knew i have done some mistake but i couldn't figure where. So, thatcs the reason I came to stack exchange.. I have another question. Should we arrange the eigen vectors rowise or column wise in P?

Comment: (What I meant was: you should have guessed your mistake was only calculatory, not conceptual.) Columnwise, like you did. It is because $A$ applies to each *column* eigenvector to produce a multiple of it, whence $AP=PD.$

Answer (score 1):

You only need continue, when the eigenvalue is $-2$, the eigenspace can be find with the definition directly, as in the other eigenvalue
$$E_{-2}=\{(x,y,z)\in {\bf R}^3: Av=-2v\}$$
That is,
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
3&-3&3&0\\
3&-3&3&0\\
6&-6&6&0
\end{array}\right]\sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]\implies x-y+z=0 $$
Then,
$$E_{-2}=\{(x,y,z)\in{\bf R}^3: x-y+z=0\}={\rm span}\{(1,1,0),(-1,0,1)\}$$
Similar with the other eigenvalue. Thus,
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&1\\0&1&1\\1&0&2\end{bmatrix}, \quad D=\begin{bmatrix}-2&0&0\\0&-2&0\\ 0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Sayan Bose already knows that.

Comment: yeah i did that and for eigen value=4 the vector is  1,1,0 

SO, P= [1 -1 1; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]. But then det(P)=0. SO, I cant find P^-1

Comment: @SayanBose: Look at the second eigenvector with my answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval: What does Sayan already know? I only try to give complete answers when the post is clear (at least to me). The comments discussions extension is not part of MathSE.

Comment: @A.P. Thanks. I had done a mistake there i guess

Comment: It is a pleasure to help you. Success in studies! @SayanBose

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly done, since you already found two independent eigenvectors for $-2,$ namely $(1,1,0)^T$ and $(-1,0,1)^T.$

An eigenvector for $4$ is $(1,1,2)^T.$

These 3 columns will do for $P.$

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort!